# how to download gridview in excel in ASP.NET C #, ie How to use group by in datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, datagridview

If I have a DataTable with the following layout:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| First | Number1 |
| First | Number2 |
| Second | Number1 |
| Second | Number2 |
| Second | Number3 |

I need to download datatable in gridview in Excel to be like table here:

| Column |
| --- |
| First |
| Number1 |
| Number2 |
| Second |
| Number1 |
| Number2 |
| Number3 |

I've seen LINQ used a lot, but I'm new to this, so I'm not very good at LINQ.

Can you please help?

Code:

```
private DataTable QR (int ID) 
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    string queryQ = @"some query here to take data from database";
       
    sqlConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryQ, sqlConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dataTableQ  = new DataTable();
    dataTableQ.Load(dr);

    // after that I'm little confused 
    DataTable dtq = new DataTable();
    var l = new List<string>();
    var gg = dtq.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(r => (string)r["QT"]);

    foreach (var g in gg)
    {
        l.Add(g.Key);

        foreach (var r in g)
            l.Add((string)r["SubQT"]);
    }
        
    HttpContext.Current.Session["_dataTableForExportInExcel1"] = dtq;
    return dtq;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, be prepared for an accident that makes a mess of your data with this "associated by position" idea

I wouldn't use LINQ for this either

```
var l = new List<string>();
string prev = null;
foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows){
  var s = (string)r["Column1"];
  var t = (string)r["Column2"];

  if(s != prev){
    l.Add(s);
    prev = s;
  } 
  l.Add(t);
}
```

Desperate for something that uses LINQ?

```
var l = new List<string>();
var gg = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(r => (string)r["Column1"]);
foreach(var g in gg){
  l.Add(g.Key);
  foreach(var r in g)
    l.Add((string)r["Column2"]);
}
```

---

So you want the output as a datatable - add to a datatable instead of a list:

```
var l = new DataTable();
l.Columns.Add("X");
string prev = null;
foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows){
  var s = (string)r["Column1"];
  var t = (string)r["Column2"];

  if(s != prev){
    l.Rows.Add(s);
    prev = s;
  } 
  l.Rows.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: No, LINQ isn't a binding solution to this problem. I thought the LINQ was the best, but all solutions are welcome, just to fix this problem.

Comment: It can be good practive, but it's important to realize that LINQ is often jsut a shorthand way of writing some loops, and that sometimes brevity does not translate to clarity, or performance ;D

Comment: can you help me, I'm a little lost in the code.

This is my code where I fill in the grid.

Comment: Code in comments in nearly impossible to follow; you should edit into the question... You appear to have loaded data into one datatable and then grouped another, empty table, and then thrown away the generated list and added an empty table to the session

Comment: I'm an update question, I'm new here and so while I manage.

Comment: So, you've just pasted my code, which fills a list, straight into your code, that either side of it uses a DataTable.. Do you see that you thus spend time building up a list and then throw it away? Adding those strings to a list was never going to add them to your DataTable dtq. Change the List for a DataTable and add to that

Comment: Also, remember that the data is in dataTableQ, not dtq

Comment: Yes, I want the output as a datatable. This example help me, and working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could process the grid out to a csv, or actually, I would suggest you do this on the table that drives, fills the gridview.

Say we have this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover">
        </asp:GridView>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="As Csv" Width="126px" />
        <br />
        <br />
```

Ok, our code to fill this grid view would be this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = LoadGrid();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    DataTable LoadGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT City, HotelName from tblHotels ORDER BY City, HotelName",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            dt.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Ok, at this point out output is this:

[image]

so, we want to flatten to one column, group by City.
(really the same problem as your example).

So the button code is this:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = LoadGrid();

        DataTable OutTable = new DataTable();
        OutTable.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(string));

        string strGroup = "";
        foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dRow[0].ToString() != strGroup)
            {
                strGroup = dRow[0].ToString();
                OutTable.Rows.Add(strGroup);
            }
            OutTable.Rows.Add(dRow[1].ToString());
        }

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=mydata.csv");
        Response.Write(toCsvT(OutTable));
        Response.End();
    }
```

And the table to csv routine is this:

```
   public string toCsvT(DataTable dt)
    {
        string strCSV = "";
        string q = "\"";
        // csv heading
        foreach (DataColumn hCol in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (strCSV != "")
                strCSV += ",";
            strCSV += q + hCol.ColumnName + q;
        }
        strCSV += System.Environment.NewLine;

        // csv data
        foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            string strOneRow = "";
            for (var i = 0; i <= dRow.Table.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (strOneRow != "")
                    strOneRow += ",";
                strOneRow += q + dRow[i] + q;
            }
            strCSV += strOneRow + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return strCSV;
    }
```

So, we probably could have processed each row on the DataGrid, but it better to spend the time to create a table to csv routine - we can use that routine many other places.

So, I much suggest re-processing the table (data source) to the new required format.

However, you can use VERY much near the same code I used for the datatable, and use the datagrid rows as the data source (you would use .cells[0] and .cells[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxlpC.png) from a DataGridItem (each row). But above I think is better.

This, when we click on the button, it downloads, and clicking on open, we get this:

[image]